# react native expo go cannot connect to localhost after uvicorn https

Tags: react-native, https, fastapi, uvicorn, expo-go

I am writing a react native expo go app with fastapi backend.
It's an educational app so, it has image, video and pdf etc..

React Native Image component was not loading images on ios emulator and I found out that I needed to run my server with https otherwise images will not load since this is requirement by Apple. After some painful attempts, I managed to run uvicorn with ssl on my local machine.

After a days setup and config attempts, I cannot get expo go to connect to server. Expo Go keeps giving Network request failed error.

My uvicorn -> fastapi server runs on 127.0.0.1:8432 or localhost:8432 with SSL.
I checked out the swagger docs and they work with both addresses with SSL ( localhost & 127.0.0.1 ).

On the Expo go side, I tried both https://127.0.0.1:8432 and localhost:8432 as well as my local area network ip 192.168.1.56 and none of them work for expo go.

Everything works fine without running https but then ios emulator won't load images or videos. Anything really... only text loads successfully.

So, what is my option here? Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

I need to answer this myself since it has costed me sometime.
I thought the whole not loading Image from network was due to ATS ( AppTransportSecurity ) issue due to apple not allowing loading images from non https connections. It turns out yes there was an issue like this documented in many questions in many sites including here.
However, this issue is not valid anymore, so if someone sees this, they will know it has a very simple solution and not related to the older issue.

If you want images loading you just have to specify the size.

```js
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: lesson.PosterUrl, // lesson.PosterUrl is string
            }}
          />
```

won't load image where this code below will:

```js
          <Image
            source={{
              uri: lesson.PosterUrl,
            }}
            style={{ width: 360, height: 360 }}
          />
```